# How to get new image path

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I need pass saved image path to new component, but I can't get it from `if` condition. This is my code:

```
 public imagePath: string;
    constructor() {}
    async selectPhoto(): Promise<any> {
        let context = imagepicker.create({
            mode: "single"
        });
        await context.authorize();
        const selection  = await context.present();
        const source = new ImageSource();
        source.fromAsset(selection[0])
            .then((imageSource: ImageSource) => {
                const folderPath: string = knownFolders.documents().path;
                const fileName = 'img_' + new Date().getTime()+ '.jpg';
                const filePath = path.join(folderPath, fileName);
                console.log('Path: ',filePath);
                const saved: boolean = imageSource.saveToFile(filePath, "jpg");
                if (saved) {
                    console.log("Image saved");
                    this.imagePath = filePath;
                }
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log("Error ");
                console.log(e);
            });
            console.log("New path: ", this.imagePath);
            return selection[0];
    }
```

I tried make saving image as distinct function and get `filePath`, but it not works. `console.log("New path: ", this.imagePath)` return error : *New path: undefined*

Comment: You are not handling the promise properly here. You are logging image path before it's saved. Try moving the log statement right after the assignment on imagePath.

Comment: @Manoj is correct, your `source.fromAsset` statement causes `selectPhoto()` to return instantly, instead of waiting on the rest of the commands to be executed. Try adding a return statement -  `return source.fromAsset(...)`.

Comment: @Monkpit I tried this: gist.github.com/marpisz96/d59b3fe1f95236c3a41a733cae3d54d6 , but I don't understand where I must use `return source.fromAsset(...)` I have to return the image and pass on its path to the new component

Comment: The reason is that `source.fromAsset` is a promise, and you need to return that promise from your outer `selectPhoto` function - otherwise `source.fromAsset` is doing work but never returning any values (even though you have written `return selection[0]`, it is not actually "going anywhere". Check out the book "Javascript: The good parts" for a really great overview of how promises and closures work in Javascript.